# How to display Date and Time value in a p:calender

Tags: primefaces

I have an xhtml page

```
<p:outputPanel>
    <p:outputLabel id="temp1"
    for="temp11" value="Start Date:" />
    <p:calendar id="startDateId"
    widgetVar="startDateFromVar" title="#"
    showOn="button" disabled="true"/>
</p:outputPanel>
```

**bean**

```
private String date;

/**
     * @return the Date
     */
    public String getDate() {
        date = "11/10/2012 19:15";
        return date;
    }

    /**
     * @param Date the Date to set
     */
    public void setDate(String ate) {
        this.date = date;
    }
```

How to show date in xhtml? I have been adding this line in  `p:calendar`
value=#{bean.date}

but it's not showing the date as well as the calender icon.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For starters, your `date` variable should be of `java.util.Date` and not a `String`. Change that to a date type and set the format on the <p:calendar/> post more of your xhtml page here. Where is the `<h:form/>` on that page? And why is the calendar rendered with `disabled="true"`?

Answer (score 1):

The value you display with `<p:calendar/>` should be type of `java.util.Date` (as kolossus already pointed out). In case if you already have a known string representation of the date, you need to parse that string with `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` to get a `java.util.Date` object:

```
private void parserDate() {
    String dateStr = "11/10/2012 19:15";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    try {
        date = formatter.parse(dateStr);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        // handle
    }
}

public Date getDate() {
    if (date == null)
        parserDate();
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

The display pattern of the calendar element can also be formatted. To display the date with the same formatting as `dateStr` use the `pattern` attribute:

```
<p:calendar id="startDateId" value="#{bean.date}" disabled="true"
                    widgetVar="startDateFromVar" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"/>
```

---

- if you use the `disabled="true"`option on your calendar, use `p:inputText` instead to display your `private String date`. Then you can eliminate the additional parsing and formatting:

  ```
  <p:inputText value="#{bean.date}" disabled="true"/>
  ```
- pointing to an ID in `<p:outputLabel for="..."/>` which doesn't exist, results in `FacesException`. Maybe you wanted:

  ```
  <p:outputLabel id="temp1" for="startDateId" value="Start Date:" />
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Since the StackOverflow just epically revived this question into the homepage, let me try to answer it.

There are lots of problems here. Let's start in the begin:

1) Your date in the bean is not a real date. It is a String! The solution is that easy: change your bean to handle java.util.Date instead of java.lang.String if you want to handle dates.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class MyDateBean {

    private Date date;

    public Date getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

2) If you want just to show the date, use the default outputtext JSF component to do it. Remember to add the converter with the desired format:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myDateBean.date}" >
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" />
</h:outputText>
```

By the way, the component you have used:

```
<p:calendar id="startDateId"
    widgetVar="startDateFromVar" title="#"
    showOn="button" disabled="true"/>
```

Is a primefaces calendar component to allow users to pick dates from a calendar panel. If you need it do something like that:

```
<p:calendar id="startDateId" value="#{myDateBean.date}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
```

to obtain:

[image]

There are some customisations you can apply. Please refer the Primefaces Demo Page to learn more about the Calendar Primefaces Component: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml

Comment: Thanks, can you point out the major (relevant) differences to the other answer? Seems identical to me (but I just did a semi-quick-scan)